Protected and "package-private" visibility when inheriting from class in different package
I'm kind of new to visibility and want to really internilize these concepts.
I've learnt that "package-private", the default visibility in Java, allows us to see fields from classes in the same package; and that protected, apart from implying package visibility,
also allows us, from class Child in otherPackage, get fields declared in Parent class in thisPackage,
as long as we are asking for them to an instance of class Child or a descendant.
However, this case really confuses me:
package thisPackage;

public class Parent {

  protected int protectedField;
  int packagePrivateField;

}

package otherPackage;
import thisPackage.Parent;

public class ChildOtherPackage extends Parent {
    
}

Under this situation, I would guess that this code wouldn't work (because we are asking an instance of ChildOtherPackage for the protected field, and ChildOtherPackage does not inherit from GrandChild), but it does:
package thisPackage;

import otherPackage.ChildOtherPackage;

public class GrandChild extends ChildOtherPackage {
    
    public void test (ChildOtherPackage c) {
        System.out.println(c.protectedField);
    }
    
}

And also, this code that I would expect to work (because classes GrandChild and Parent are declared in the same
package), doesn't:

package thisPackage;

import otherPackage.ChildOtherPackage;

public class GrandChild extends ChildOtherPackage {
    
    public void test (GrandChild g) {
        System.out.println(g.packagePrivateField); // Error: packagePrivateField is not public in Parent; cannot be accessed from outside package
    }
    
}

What's going on here? Maybe the behaviour in the second example has to do with the fact that inheritance really represent implicit composition internally and when we ask for g.packagePrivateField, g asks his internal ChildOtherPackage object for the packagePrivateField, and in this question we are soliciting a package-private field from outside the package thisPackage; but I'm not really sure.
Any help is really appreciated.
TL;DR: I expected (under the environment of the first two code snippets) the first code not to work and the second one to work, and neither of those happened.

since ChildOtherPackage only inherits the members it can see, you may think of it as being declared as class ChildOtherPackage { /* inherited */ protected int protectedField; /* packagePrivateField not inherited */ } and just forget about the grand-parent of GrandChild - it can see protectedField, but threre is no packagePrivateField to see - details JLS 6.6. Access Control

Although it’s not emphasized, the Java Language Specification addresses the protected behavior:  “Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C. … If the access is by … a field access expression of the form Primary.Id, then access to the instance field Id is permitted if and only if the qualifying type is S or a subclass of S.”

In the first case, accessing c.protectedField is allowed because you are accessing it from the same package in which protectedField is declared. You even said "apart from implying package visibility..." yourself.
From the Access Control section of the Java Language Specification,


Otherwise, if the member or constructor is declared protected, then access is permitted only when one of the following is true:

Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package containing the class in which the protected member or
constructor is declared.

Access is correct as described in §6.6.2.





The access is in the same package, so whatever §6.6.2 says doesn't even matter.

In the second case, accessing c.packagePrivateField does not compile, because packagePrivateField is not a member of GrandChild.
The relevant section of the JLS is Class Members.

The members of a class are all of the following:

Members inherited from its direct superclass type (§8.1.4), except in the class Object, which has no direct superclass type
...



Only members of a class that are declared protected or public are inherited by subclasses declared in a package other than the one in which the class is declared.

From this, we can see that ChildOtherPackage inherits the protectedField, but does not inherit packagePrivateField, because ChildOtherPackage is declared in the package thatPackage, not thisPackage.
As a result, packagePrivateField is not a member of GrandChild either, because only members of the direct superclass is inherited.
This is ultimately because packagePrivateField is package private, so presumably that is why the error message points out the accessibility issue, instead of something like "cannot resolve symbol..." like it normally does when you try to access a non-existent member.

Ok I totally get what you are saying. But I think what the Java doc refers to when saying "Only members of a class that are declared protected or public are inherited by subclasses declared in a package other than the one in which the class is declared." is that, as normally, the class will look recursively in its parent for the field, and when some parent asks for the package-private field out of the package, it will fail.
That's the only reasonable explanation on why the error is that way: it actually went up in the inheritance tree to ChildOtherPackage and there the error ocurred.

Your first test works, because GrandChild  has access to the protectedField and can therefore use its own protectedField and that of every other class. (This also works with private fields within a class: You can access the private fields of a different object that is an instanceof the same class).
The second test fails, because the GrandChild tries to find the packagePrivateField in its direct parent, which searches it in its parent. But since ChildOtherPackage has no access to the packagePrivateField, it does not provide it to the GrandChild. This means, that a class can only check its parent, never its grand-parent. But the parent check works recursively.

I understand the second part of your comment, but I don't know what you mean by "its own protectedField"

I meant, that you can access the protectedField in the object's instance as usual, but also the protectedField of every other instance of the class.
